# Add a user generated node to the end of a linked list in C

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, allocation

I think i'm screwing up something simple i'm not seeing, but what's supposed to happen is a menu option to add a new node is selected. The main program creates a new node, passes it to a function that adds it to the end of a linked list. Below are code snippets that should help explain what i did.

Node declaration:

```
typedef struct Node {
    char fname[51];
    char lname[51];
    int idnum;
    float scores[5];
    float average;

    struct Node *next;
} Node;
```

New node creation and user assigned values:

```
 case 'A':
     entry = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
     printf("Enter the name of the record you would like to append\nFirst:");
     scanf("%50s", &(*entry).fname);
     printf("\nLast:\n");
     scanf(" %50s", &(*entry).lname);
     printf("Enter the ID of the record you would like to append\n");
     scanf("%d", &(*entry).idnum);
     printf("Enter the scores of the record you would like to append\n");
     for(j=0;j<5;j++) {
         scanf("%f", &(*entry).scores[j]);
     }
     head = addend(head,entry);
     printrecords(head,disp);
break;
```

Add node to end of linked list:

```
Node* addend(Node* head, Node* entry) {
    if(head == NULL) {
            return NULL;
    }

    Node *cursor = head;
    while(cursor->next != NULL) {
            cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    cursor->next = entry;

    return head;
```

}

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

SOLVED:

not sure why I was creating a new node when I passed the node that I wanted to assign to it. Code updated to reflect that. Also as @jose_Fonte pointed out, this code is risky to use in a formal setting as the reference to head could be lost.

Comment: `head = NULL` this isn't doing what you're intending.

Comment: Should that be "==" instead?

Comment: Indeed, `=` is an assignment.

Comment: `if(head = NULL) {` implies you do not have your compilers warnings fully enabled. (I'd expect a a warning)  Save time, enable them all or get a new compiler.

Comment: Code updated to also include a break in that case as that was also missing.

Comment: You have quite a few errors in the code. Try to use some encapsulation to the single linked list, some functions to set/get data from a node and last but not least, your addend function will make you lose the reference to the head node if somehow your assertions fail. Divide and conquer your problem.

Comment: I've solved it to accomplish what I intended, but Jose do you have any articles I could look at to accomplish what you're referencing?

Comment: `entry->Next` should be set to NULL, `malloc`returns uninitialized memory.

Comment: `addend` could eventually return a true/false (boolean) value assuring the user that the new node was added successfully as you already "own" a reference to the head. Then instead of creating manually a new node you could do a function that returns a new node, e.g., `create_new_node()` which could just return `(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));`. You could also do functions like `node_set_first_name(...)` where you could validate the arguments instead of throwing a pointer to the struct field into scanf (this would apply to all structure members, setters/getters). This would improve your code.

Comment: in the mean time instead of `head = addend(head,entry);` just use something like `result_head = addend(head,entry);` and then `if (result_head != NULL) { head = result_head; }` which is kind of redundant but avoids setting the head as NULL if the assertions fail.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed it add an item to the end of a single linked list. It's ruining the whole idea of O(1) complexity of add/remove operations this structure is based upon. It's meant to grow from the front side or after an item you keeping your node pointer to. Therefore, I'd write `add_after` method taking two parameters: a pointer to a node after it'll insert a new node and a pointer to a new node. You can keep a pointer to a new node and use it sequentially, to grow your linked list from its back side.